# Does an upward js heap chart means a memory leak

Tags: javascript, performance, scroll, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Does these chart indicate a serious memory leak? Or its just normal to go on since its capture first for 5 s and second one for 10s.

I have a throttled scroll watcher on two divs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYNRY.png) suggests of a strong memory leak.

> The JS heap graph (the blue graph) is not as straightforward. In keeping with best practices, the first dip is actually a garbage collection. As the recording progresses you can see that the JS heap size spikes. This is natural and expected: the JavaScript code is creating the DOM nodes and doing a lot of work when it creates the string of one million characters. The key thing here is the fact that the JS heap ends higher than it began (the “beginning” here being the point after the forced garbage collection). In the real world, if you saw this pattern of increasing JS heap size or node size, it would potentially mean a memory leak.

Extract from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis?hl=en).

Try doing the few things like:

- Reuse the object and arrays instead re-creating them.
- Avoid unneccesary variable declarations.
- Keep a watch on the closures.
- Try breaking the object link if of no use.

You might read this [article](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks) on how to deal with memory management in JS.

There is a garbage cleaning that the browser schedules up often after a certain limit.On inspecting the timeline you would find there is `Major GC collected`.Now the compiler cleans those nodes, which are unnaccesible. Somehow with heavy use of recursion or closures, there is some or the other link to the variables still being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is definitely a memory leak. The second one appears to be the same sawtooth pattern that appears when using `setInterval`/`setInterval`. Technically the latter isn't a memory leak, but be careful with how you use them. Take a look at the differences between a recursive timeout and an interval, since intervals could allow the callback it's supposed to run be executed after an interval has ended, but before the first callback has finished executing.

Some notes:

- be very careful with closures, especially with their scope and context compared to those of its surrounding function

  - it's possible to trap large variables within a function through circular references, e.g. the following, which leaks `str` because it's within `logSomething`'s native scope object:

    ```
    function leaks() {
        let str = 'a'.repeat(Math.pow(10, 8)); // 1 billion
        const referenceStr = () => str === 'b'.repeat(Math.pow(10, 8));
        const logSomething = () => console.log('leaking...');
        referenceStr();
        setInterval(logSomething, 60 * 1000);
    }

    setInterval(leaks, 60 * 1000);
    ```
  - similarly, making a circular reference between the DOM and javascript land. This function leaks `str` since `body` holds a reference to the DOM, its `onclick` handler holds a reference back to the javascript world, which also holds a reference to `str` in its native scope object, and `body` is never nulled, keeping the DOM element in the javascript world as well.

    ```
    (function leaks() {
        let str = 'a'.repeat(Math.pow(10, 8));
        let body = document.body;
        body.onclick = () => alert(str);
    })();

    setInterval(() => document.body.click(), 60 * 1000);
    ```
- always delete event handlers after you are finished with them.
  Deleting an object using event handlers without removing all of them
  beforehand may cause a leak